# jquery focusing to number input not trigger the num keyboard for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

As soon as my page loads, I am focusing the user to enter the first number to the otp. when i do this by jquery, by default num keyboard not visible.later my manually if i focus,I am getting the num keyboard. how to salve this issue?

here is my code :

```
setTimeout(function(){
                Ember.$('.digit0').focus(); 
            }, 100 );
```

my html:

```
{{#each cardDigitField as  |field index| }}
                 <input type="number" tabindex="{{count}}" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" value='' 
                    pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"
                    onKeyUp={{action "numberEntered" index }} 
                    onKeyPress={{action "numberInit" }}
                    onPaste={{action "numberPaste" }} class="digit{{index}}" > 
                    {{#if requiredHyphen}}
                        {{add-hyphen index 4 cardDigitField.length}}
                    {{/if}}
            {{/each}}
```

Comment: Did you try `autofocus` property of [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally `setTimeout` and Ember's runloop don't play together very well. If you use the `afterRender` hook in your component and then your jQuery do you have better success?